# http redirection to the previous host ip address in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

IP address of the host which wso2am is running on has been changed. in wso2am when I am trying to go to publisher page, it redirects me to previous IP address for authentication so that i can not go to publisher page. any idea how can i solve this redirection problem?

Comment: Have you tried the steps in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/#troubleshooting-registered-callback-does-not-match-with-the-provided-url-error

Answer (score 0):

In the deployment.toml you can change the following. Here you can use a hostname (Recommended) or an IP address.

```
[server]
hostname = "am.dev.wso2.com"
```

Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/#changing-the-hostname